# How to add custom shape to spannable String in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap, android-bitmap

I got stuck in this problem since yesterday. I am using `spannable string` and want to add custom shape to it similar to [chips](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/chips.html):

Here is my code where I am modifying the `spannable` string:

```
s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(backgroundColor), currentIndex, currentIndex + words[i].length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I tried with `Bitmap` but according to process I need to convert my `Editable` with `BitmapDrawable` as per the code:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(textView);
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not using `textView`. I am working on `AutoCompleteTextView` and converting `AutoCompleteTextView` to `Bitmap` is impossible (If I am not wrong here).

How can I achieve the similar result?

## Edit-1

I used following `shape`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#A6B0B8" />
<gradient android:startColor="#E5E5E6"
    android:endColor="#B4B6B7"
    android:angle="-270"/>
<corners  android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

## Custom Drawable

```
public class CustomDrawble extends DynamicDrawableSpan {

private Context mContext;

CustomDrawble(Context context){
    super();
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable() {
    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble);
    drawable.setBounds(0,0,100,20);
    return drawable;
}
}
```

For applying above `Drawable` I used following code:

```
 s.setSpan(new CustomDrawble(mContext), currentIndex, currentIndex + words[i].length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

From the #Edit-1 section I am getting this:

[image]

What I am doing wrong here? I am using `Widget.SearchView` not a `TextView`

Comment: try this http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/.

Comment: @HosseinGerami It's just transforming the text and adding Border to it. I have already done this with `BackgroundColorSpan` (Have a look in the code)

Comment: ok. or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161594/android-autocompletetextview-with-chips

Comment: @HosseinGerami If I am not wrong then every link is talking about `EditText` or `TextView` But as I have mentioned in question that I am using `Editable`

Comment: this using autocompletetextview http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/. ok?

Comment: @HosseinGerami No offence but it's completely a  different problem and How do you think that it will create bubble to editable ?

Comment: use `DynameicDrawableSpan`

Comment: @pskink I followed a SO question and implemented with `DynamicDrawableSpan `. Please have a look at the Edit-1 section

Comment: it is ok, your Drawables have size 100x20

Comment: @pskink can you please provide me reference for `setBound` method. So that I can fix it. BTW I found it but it's not understandable 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds(int, int, int, int)  . It sounds like they are talking about co-ordinates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93229/discussion-between-amit-pal-and-pskink).