# How to make an edittext with custom card item like message application?

Tags: android

I want to make an edittext to let user choose receivers like message application or mail application:
[image]

with a custom adapter(data is in my database, not in contact list android or something like that)

how can I make it? I discovered auto completed edittext but I still not figure out this case?
Thank u in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AutoCompleteTextView with chips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161594/android-autocompletetextview-with-chips)

Comment: no, chips uses data from contact, gmail.... available on android. in my case, i use data from my database!

Comment: No, chips are just those visual components. You can back them with whatever dataset you want.

Comment: Oh, thank u. Let me try this :D